# Why only C++(and D language) provides variadic templates feature? Are variadic templates that good?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, programming-languages, variadic-templates

Why is only C++ (and D language) out of many programming languages out there supporting variadic templates?

Is there a MAJOR BENEFIT of providing this feature to the language?

Or the underlying complexity and the compilation time increase (due to type checking) make it rather not worth the effort?

Where do I know that only C++ (and D language) supports variadic templates?

Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template

Comment: *Where do I know that only C++ supports variadic templates?* => the very Wikipedia link you cite also mentions that D supports variadic templates, which does not support your claim.

Comment: I am not sure this question fits the StackOverflow model, it seems too broad and likely to attract (bad) subjective answers. May I invite you to post it to https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages/ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Common Lisp provides much better than variadic templates thru its macro system (beware, Lisp macros are much more powerful than C++ templates or macros for its preprocessor). Lisp predates C++ (and C) by decades! Try [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) (a freely available excellent Common Lisp implementation).

<sup>BTW, I think that [D](https://dlang.org/) and [Terra](http://terralang.org/) and [Template Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Haskell) also have something similar to variadic templates, and probably other languages too .... I cannot explain why Lisp ideas vanished, the reasons are more sociological, educational and economical than technical; read also [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), [*Practical Common Lisp*](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) and [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces).</sup>

Many (academic mostly) programming languages provide [**homoiconicity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity): code is data, and data is code - and is proof- (read about the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), [Gödel incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems), [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), [GEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) book, [Partial Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation), ...) . Read also about [multi-stage programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_programming) (a type-safer form of metaprogramming). Read about [CAIA](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2016/12/bootstrapping-caia-part-i-the-initial-domain/) on J.Pitrat's blog.

On modern operating systems (e.g. Linux) with [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) of [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) (with [dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)), it is possible (and sometimes interesting) to generate some C (or C++) code in some temporary file -i.e. to "[compile to C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065)" (or to generated C++) your [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), compile that as a temporary plugin, and use it in the same run.

C++ template machinery is some (uncomplete) form of [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming). Generating C or C++ code (wrongly called [source code generation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/361458/40065)) and `dlopen`ing the corresponding plugin is another form of metaprogramming. And you could also use [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) approaches (e.g. with libraries like [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), LLVM, libjit, GNU lightning, etc...) to generate code at runtime.

---

<sup>The intuition (regarding the power of Common Lisp macros) is that a macro expansion in Lisp can do *arbitrary* computation (expressed in the *same* Lisp language) at *compile* time, and that LISP [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s (called [S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)-s) are easily processable in Lisp. Of course the "compilation" process in Lisp is very different than that of C++ (and most Common Lisp applications contain the compiler). Hence the equivalent of [RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), of [SWIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG), of [s11n](http://s11n.net/), of [Lemon](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) can easily (and routinely) be done thru Common Lisp macros (of course that is not possible in C++ in the *same* program). But you need to read several books to grasp that powerful idea, so I don't claim to be able to explain it easily</sup>

Comment: Can you please give an example/link, where we can see that lisp's macro system is much better than templates? Thanks!

Comment: No I cannot. You'll need entire books to explain that. Read first SICP, and then read some good Common Lisp book and [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces). But these books are worth reading. Look also into Scott's [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/). Play with SBCL for a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the references, I may read SICP. But lisp is a different world for a C++ programmer, this is a huge topic (I know, because I configured ("programmed") emacs in lisp a little bit, but I didn't understand at all, what I was doing...). Can't you give at least a clue, a simple direction, where lisp macro system is better? Like: "lisp macro system is better, because you can do XXX in it". Its main strength.

Comment: No, really I cannot. The intuition is that a macro expansion in Lisp can do *arbitrary* computation (expressed in the *same* Lisp language), and that LISP ASTs (called [S-expr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)) are easily processable in Lisp. Beyond that intuition, you need books. This is not true in C++: you cannot metaprogram something which generates a print routine of all scalar fields (in a given class) whose name starts with two lowercase letters....

Comment: ... you can't (easily) code in C++ template language, the equivalent of [RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), of [SWIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG), of [s11n](http://s11n.net/), of [Lemon](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/). Doing all that in Common Lisp is easy and common.

Comment: Thanks, that's an example what I was asking for. Now I see lisp is a very powerful language, indeed. I like this.

Comment: And the point is that SBCL is *dynamically* generating machine code (at *every* [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interaction, at every `defun`, `eval`, or `compile`) and the generated machine code can be (when giving some annotations) as efficient as optimized C code. BTW, machine code is garbage collected too (not only data) in SBCL

Comment: I wonder what's the reason that lisp is not that popular in commercial software then. It looks like a simple (in a positive sense, compared to C++) yet powerful language.

Comment: @geza, ESR recently [reflected](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=7745) on this: «The failure mode of academic languages is predictable; high inward transition costs, nobody goes there, failure to achieve community critical mass sufficient for mainstream adoption, isolation, and stagnation. (That’s a potted history of LISP in one sentence, and I say that as an old LISP-head with a deep love for the language…)».

Comment: @geza, basically he argues that LISP had that "high inward transition cost" while C++ had low inward transition cost (from C, which everyone was using) and was fast on that day's hardware.

Answer (score 11):

C++ is moving more towards compile-time programming features because it serves what C++ is exactly looking for: Performance.

With variadic templates and all the wonderful [type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) features of C++ you can make very generic programs that will have almost zero impact on performance at run-time. An example is [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library, where it uses templates very heavily to map to raw C functions of LAPACK, which is extremely difficult to use and error prone. Armadillo made it super-easy, performant and type-safe at the same time with a thin C++ layer.

Comment: @VladimirF I made a whole library that imitates Armadillo myself due to some licensing issues, feel free to visit it [here](https://git.afach.de/samerafach/Polymath). It's not about not being able to do it; you don't seem to understand the point. Yes, it's extremely difficult to use. Do you really want to compare `A*B` with calling `dgemm_`?

Comment: @denis631 It's a template library, dude. Go to includes!

Comment: @VladimirF The library is an abstraction of LAPACK/Math libraries. After writing this library, which incorporates all ugly LAPACK calls, I never need to look at LAPACK again. I never need to worry about pointers. I never need to worry about type-safety. That's exactly the point. All I have to do is call simple C++ functions that will automatically get the right LAPACK function and data-type at compile-time. I find that beautiful! That's why I made it! Abstraction + Performance! Consider also people who don't need to look at LAPACK because of Armadillo and Polymath and similar libraries.